# How to delete the pattern between start of the pattern and a line before the end pattern using sed or perl command?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, ksh

Here is the input file

```
{1:IRVTUS30XXX}{2:I304dfaffaefa}{3:fewfa]}
:15A:
:20:1234556
:22:dsafas
dsafafaf
erwfafgr
:23:fewfd
:24:firh
:60:uncenjnjcdv
:72:uenuernfk
12345
-}
```

Here i want to delete some tags information from the input file. (Tags are :15A:  :22:  which are in between colon are called tags)

If i want to delete tag 20 i can use the below perl command:

```
perl -i -pe 's/:20:(.*)\r\n//g' file
```

But for the tags like :22: or :72: its mulitiple line tags.. How can i delete those?

Comment: `whciha re`, that is quite an astounding typo.

Comment: Here's a hint: To match a multi-line string, you cannot read the file in line-by-line mode.

Comment: Given the data you show, we have to infer the rules of the format, which are not obvious — it is not a common format. It seems that lines starting with `{` are likely have some significance as a 'start of group' marker. There seem to be 'tags' which are lines that start with a colon, 2 or 3 alphanumerics and another colon; these may be followed by non-empty data, possibly spread over several lines where the continuation lines do not start with a tag. There are also lines that contain `-}`; it is not clear whether this is simply part of the data for the preceding tag (`:72:`) or something else.

Comment: We really shouldn't have to guess about this, though; you should be telling us about the rules of the format, so we know whether the `-}` line is to be kept or deleted.  It may be obvious to you; it isn't obvious to an outsider.

Comment: Am sorry.. the -} is the end of the message so it should not be deleted as part of Tag 72..

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the expression to select both tag no. **22** and tag no. **72**:

```
:(72|22):([\w\d]*(\r?\n|\r\n?)+)+
```

[Here](http://regexr.com?36ne9)'s a test of match.

Comment: You have perhaps missed the multi-line match part of the question. Also, `(\r?\n|\r\n?)+` is better written `[\r\n]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for removing tag 22 (works with multi-lines or single line):

```
% perl -00 -pe 's/^:22:.*?(?=(?:^:\d+\w*|$))//ms' file.txt
{1:IRVTUS30XXX}{2:I304dfaffaefa}{3:fewfa]}
:15A:
:20:1234556
:23:fewfd
:24:firh
:60:uncenjnjcdv
:72:uenuernfk
12345
-}
```

Comment: This seems to be deleting the lines but i see the empty line in the position of the tag which got deleted and also subsequents tags are not getting deleted..